# Convert Java Code to Jython Code

Tags: java, jython

I want to convert this sample of Java code to jython code

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class GetSpecifications {

    public static void main(String[] args){

     long memorySize = ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean())

                .getTotalPhysicalMemorySize(); //casting 

        System.out.println(memorySize);

    }
}
```

Comment: these two lines of Java code are used for getting size of physical memory

Comment: i have tried to get memory size of my pc and this code enable me to get it, but; Now i want to convert this java code to jython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jython, casts are unnecessary because the language automatically looks up methods as needed.

Therefore, your code would simply be

```
from java.lang.management import ManagementFactory
print ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()
```